# webpack-dev-server has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

All I've done so far is follow the guide on webpack.

Windows 10.

Initially I was using node v6.11.1, but I've now upgraded to 8.5.0 to see if that fixed the issue; no dice.

I've read somewhere that `webpack-dev-server` needed to be installed globally, so I tried that as well; also no dice.

The full error I'm getting:

```
Invalid configuration object. webpack-dev-server has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'error'. These properties are valid:
   object { hot?, hotOnly?, lazy?, bonjour?, host?, allowedHosts?, filename?, publicPath?, port?, socket?, watchOptions?, headers?, clientLogLevel?, overlay?, progress?, key?, cert?, ca?, pfx?, pfxPassphrase?, requestCert?, inline?, disableHostCheck?, public?, https?, contentBase?, watchContentBase?, open?, useLocalIp?, openPage?, features?, compress?, proxy?, historyApiFallback?, staticOptions?, setup?, stats?, reporter?, noInfo?, quiet?, serverSideRender?, index?, log?, warn? }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-demo@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-demo@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! 2017-09-14T13_46_40_808Z-debug.log
```

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
        print: './src/print.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Management'
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
}
```

And my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that really the webpack config that is being used? It doesn't look like it, because you don't have any property called `error`.

Comment: It is. I know, I was confused about that as well. I don't have any other `webpack.config.js` files.

Comment: Can you try to run it with the explicit config path, for example `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js`?

Comment: I think I just found the issue and did a *headdesk*. FWIW, I had tried the config but it wasn't working. What I _just_ noticed was that I was also calling `http-server` with `start` 2 lines above. And it was running in the background.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was straight up user error and an oversight.

Prior to "just following the guide" I was messing with something else and had added a `start` script using `http-server`. I don't know how many times I looked at the `package.json` and missed it, but there it is. Plain as day.

It required me closing my consoles though as it was running in the background. Once I closed and reopened the console window and ran `npm run start` the `webpack-dev-server` worked fine.

Feel free to ring the shame bell.